# Can I stop UIScrollView at scrolled position?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to stop `UIScrollView` scrolling when it reached at specific point.

I thought it will be solve by below code.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollY: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    stopScrollViewIfNeeded(by: scrollY)
}

func stopScrollViewIfNeeded(by scrollY: CGFloat) {
    guard scrollY <= SpecificY else {
        return
    }

    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

But I was wrong. because `contentOffset.y` be to 0 when scroll be disabled.

And I was improved my function like below code, but it still didn't work as I wanted.

```
func stopScrollViewIfNeeded(by scrollY: CGFloat) {
    guard scrollY <= SpecificY else {
        return
    }

    scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: SpecificY), animated: false)
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```

How do I improve `stopScrollViewIfNeeded()` to work as I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set contentOffset as:

Just need to get the offset value at which you want it to be stopped and Assign values as Below

**Horizontal ScrollView**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.MainScollView.contentOffset.x = self.view.frame.size.width*2
        }
```

or **Vertical scrollView**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.MainScollView.contentOffset.y = 90
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the scroll position in didScroll. Logic in the didScroll can effectively make the scroll stick for as long as you want.